# Azure Search Indexer fails to create when trying to index fields with special characters in the name

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to create an Azure Search indexer and i am getting the following error message:

"Azure Search notification
Import configuration failed, error creating Index: "The request is invalid. Details: definition : Invalid field name: '@type'. Field names must begin with a letter and can contain only letters, digits, or underscore ('_').""

I have my data stored in a Cosmos DB using SQL API and the documents stored there contain data following the schema.org standard, so i have fields with name starting with @, such as @type.

I know there are some questions around this, but more related with the search capabilities for fields with special characters in the name. In this case, i am not able even to index them. And in theory i should be able to do it, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *field mapping* to "rename" the problematic fields. See [Field mappings in Azure Search indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings). 
Note that because field mappings are not exposed in the portal, you will need to create the indexer programmatically using the Create Indexer REST API or corresponding .NET client SDK API.